# How to get subscribers collection in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, collection, newsletter-subscriber

I'm trying to get the collection of subscribers but can't find how to do it in Magento 2, the ones I found were about 1.9.
Is there a way to get it just like the users?

I've tried

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\file;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Export extends Action
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\CollectionFactory $subscriberCollection
    ) {
        $this->subscriberCollection = $subscriberCollection;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $subscribers = $this->subscriberCollection->create()->getCollection();

    }
}
```

But it doesn't seems to be like this.

Best regards

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Took me a while to find it but it's "Call to undefined method Magento\\Newsletter\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Subscriber\\Collection::getCollection()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this,**

```
<?php
    
    namespace vendor\module\file;
    
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    
    class Export extends Action
    {
        public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\CollectionFactory $subscriberCollection
        ) {
            $this->subscriberCollection = $subscriberCollection;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }
    
        public function execute()
        {
    
            $subscribers = $this->subscriberCollection->create();

             foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber) {
               print_r($subscriber->getData());
             }
   
    
        }
    }
```